# Tutorials on building a Webhook endpoint in .NET?

Tags: .net, webhooks

I want to implement a webhook call into a small web application to view data that's being pushed to my server/site. I fully understand how Webhooks work from the push side of the fence. I'm at a loss of where to begin on building out a web service/page/endpoint to accept the webhook call.

I've been reading/searching and pretty much all the tutorials I've seen out there deal with webhook implementation into your app. So it's not much help for me.

I can implement it in any language but have been using C#/.NET mostly so that platform would be ideal.

Any pointers to some simple basic tutorials or something would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the page that receives the post from the webhook only need to capture the right variable or the pure post. In this example I expected two params.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string subject = Request.Params["subject"];
            string message = Request.Params["body-plain"];
            Response.Write("My response");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            //this should set a 500 error...
            Response.Write("I tried, and failed:" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
</script>
```